# Triggering Shell Script from Performance Center or VuGen

Tags: bash, shell, performance-testing, loadrunner, hp-performance-center

My query here is to check if it's possible to trigger a shell script from performance center or vugen. The shell script is placed in a server which is also the same server we monitor during our load test. This shell script contains commands which will fetch the CPU and memory and mail us the details.  So is it possible to execute this shell script from PC.

```
PC ---> test starts ------------------> test ends

   +--> shell script also starts  ----> shell script execution ends ---> mail results.
```

Are there any commands to start this script on the fly or any possible ways. to do the same ? Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it from the script via init/end sections but be careful to make sure that only one vUser does that by checking if the process is already running (better do it from the target script itself)

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be triggered only once. but how can i trigger it ? are there any commands or syntax's on this please

Comment: Don't forget, CPU and Memory are only two items associated with your finite resource pool.  You also have Disk and Network.   You might also investigate SiteScope, an in-the-box product with every version of LoadRunner since version 8, which allows you to pull system stats without an agent loaded on the remote hosts, with the advantage that all of the samples are clock matched to your result sets.

Comment: sure, thanks. let me try this out and get back to you. notepad.exe is what you are referring to the shell script right? since i have this script placed in the server, shouldn't i be giving the abs path ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (you can put it in init and end files too):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);

Action() {
    system("notepad.exe");
     return 0;
}
```